# how to process data strings with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, axios

I am doing a node.js [manual](https://youtu.be/JmJ1WUoUIK4?t=13552) and trying to display the information obtained from [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)

```
app.get('/posts', async (req, res) => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    
    console.log(typeof response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
    
    res.render('posts',{
        posts: response.data,
    });
});
```

I see in the console that the data obtained is in an unreadable format

when validating the valid data type that it is a string when it should be an object (json).

[image]

**I don't know if [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) changed the way to present your information or what additional code I should add to be able to display the information in my template.**

Template code

```
<%- include('partials/header'); %>
<h1>Posts</h1>

<p><%= posts %></p>

    <% for(let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) { %>

        <article>
            <h1><%= posts[i].title %></h1>
            <p><%= posts[i].body %></p>
        </article>
        

    <% } %>



<%- include('partials/footer'); %>
```

The template shows the tag that loads all request.data because of the tag `<p><%= posts %></p>`

[image]

Comment: This appears to be an encoding problem. Check the server and the file to see if their encodings match for the specified file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with `axios` version 1.2.0. Using 1.1.3 should work well, see https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is a known bug in this version, they already fixed it in the latest version, you can check it here https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5296